# C/C++: In a nested table how do I find the top in the __index function?

Tags: lua, lua-table

In have a nested table and use a metatable with the __index function.
Inside the __index function I am receiving just the nested table and a string-index.
How can I search back to find the root of the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on how you stored your back references from the nested table to the root table. If you didn't handle the back references yourself, then you can't. A table can be stored in multiple parent tables at the same time, so there is no automatic parent/root reference you could use.

Possibilities to handle this case yourself include:

1. add a reference to the root table as an upvalue to the `__index` method
2. store a parent field (or a root field) in every nested table
3. store a mapping from nested table to parent/root table in a weak table accessible from your `__index` function.
4. ...